# JS: Why does [] + "abc" result in an array of 3 elements of letters?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm confused on the behavior of this expression in JavaScript:

```
[] + "abc"
```

I am expecting it to simply produce an array with element 0 being undefined and element 1 being "abc":

```
[, "abc"]
```

but the result is:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

This seems perhaps non-intuitive. Why is the behavior?

Comment: i get a single string ... its' because `[]` is converted to `''` (by `toString`) and the rest is an addition.

Comment: It doesn't do that. It returns the string `abc` (the empty array is cast to the empty string).

Comment: Not sure what JS Engine you are running that gives you that result. `[] + "abc"` is `[].toString() + "abc"` which would be `"" + "abc"` which would be `"abc"`

Comment: What is the exact code you are using that you think you are getting that result? My guess is there is something else going on.

Comment: @epascarello looks like i was misreading output of my actions. My output looked indistinguishable from an array of 3 separate letters. I'm using a very poorly designed debugger. you're actually right in this case. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string is returned because `[]` is casted as `""`.

`console.log([].toString());// ""

```js
const a = [] + "abc";

console.log(a);// "abc"
```

Comment: `[] is cast as 0.` I am not sure about that.... it is not zero. It is converted to a string which would be "". If what you were saying is true,  it would be `"0abc"` You get zero because `console.log(+"")`

Comment: That's not true, `[]` is "cast" as `''`, via `toString`. This is **not** the same as unary plus, which coerces to number.

Comment: If `[]` was casted to 0, the result would be `"0abc"`.

Comment: yeah, I misexplained, fix is done.